# Como descargar archivo excel desde base de datos móvil

Tags: javascript, html, ionic, phonegap

Estoy creando una aplicación móvil hibrida con ionic y cordova, en donde registro datos de clientes a través de un formulario.
Quisiera saber de que manera exportar esos datos sql a un archivo excel a mi celular o tablet a través del click a un botón en la misma app.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes generar un archivo `.csv`? Esos archivos los puede abrir [tag:excel] sin problemas.

Comment: Si. De que manera podría generar el .csv ?

Comment: Consulta la documentación de cordova e ionic. Ingrid, este sitio es para resolver problemas reales de programación. La investigación va por tu cuenta, aunque te recomiendo usar Google. Si te interesa pertenecer a esta comunidad, te invito a que visites el __[tour]__. Por favor, no te molestes si tu pregunta es cerrada porque no cumple con los estándares de calidad. Puedes mejorarla siguiendo esta guía: __[mcve]__.